# perlcritic message: map used in void context

Tags: perl, void, perl-critic

There is a Perl code line below where I get the message from `perlcritic`:

```
map { $total_ids += scalar @{$ids->{$_}} } @brands;
```

The message is:

```
"map" used in void context near 'map { $total_ids += scalar @{$ids->{$_}} } @brands;'
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` returns a list, which in void context is thrown away.

As recommended by [Perl::Critic::Policy::BuiltinFunctions::ProhibitVoidMap](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::BuiltinFunctions::ProhibitVoidMap), turn your `map` into a `foreach`

```
 $total_ids += scalar @{$ids->{$_}} foreach @brands;
```

Comment: "`map` in void context is no longer expensive. `map` is now context aware, and will not construct a list if called in void context." - from [perl581delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl581delta#Miscellaneous-Enhancements). So that hasn't been true since 2003.

Comment: Using `map` in void context is still a bad idea. But because it obfuscates your code, not because it has any actual detrimental effects.

Comment: Or just: `$total_ids += @{$ids->{$_}} for @brands;`